# Re-Draw google chart on button click / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm new to .js programming and I have a problem with google charts in javascript.
I'm using a simple HTML form where I enter some data, then on button click my script runs.

I would like the code to re-draw (or update) the chart on every button click.

The problem seems to be, that once the google library has finished loading for the first time, my script stops executing at the point where the command for loading is.

I tried the solution from this post [Google chart redraw onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640728/google-chart-redraw-onclick), but it didn't work for me.

The file looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <div id="gender">
  <h3>Gender</h3>
  <fieldset>
   <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender_select" class="optGender" value="männlich" checked><span class="optGender">male</span></input><br>
   <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender_select" class="optGender" value="weiblich" ><span class="optGender">female</span></input><br>
   Bodyweight: <input type="text" id="bodyweight"></input>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <div id="chart">
 </div>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <div id="squat">
  <p>
   <h3>Squat</h3>
   <fieldset>
    <span class="spreps">Reps</span><input type="text" id="reps_squat" required><br>
    <span class="spweight">Weight</span><input type="text" id="weight_squat" required><br>
    <span class="spmax">Calculated Max</span><input type="text" id="total_squat" readonly><br>
   </fieldset>
  </p>
 </div>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <div id="bench">
  <p> 
   <h3>Benchpress</h3>
   <fieldset>
    <span class="spreps">Reps</span><input type="text" id="reps_bench" required><br>
    <span class="spweight">Weight</span><input type="text" id="weight_bench" required><br>
    <span class="spmax">Calculated Max</span><input type="text" id="total_bench" readonly><br>
   </fieldset>
  </p>
 </div>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <div id="deadlift">
  <p>
   <h3>Deadlift</h3>
   <fieldset>
    <span class="spreps">Reps</span><input type="text" id="reps_deadlift" required><br>
    <span class="spweight">Weight</span><input type="text" id="weight_deadlift" required><br>
    <span class="spmax">Calculated Max</span><input type="text" id="total_deadlift" readonly><br>
   </fieldset>
  </p>
 </div>  
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <p>
  <input type="button" alt="Berechnen" class="button" id="btn_calcTotal" value="Total berechnen" onclick="initialize()">
 </p>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <div id="total">
  <p>
  <h3>calculated Total</h3>
   <input type="text" id="total_all" readonly>

  </p>
 </div>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
 <script>
  function initialize() {
 // delete old entries
 document.getElementById("total_squat").value = "";
 document.getElementById("total_bench").value = "";
 document.getElementById("total_deadlift").value = "";
 document.getElementById("total_all").value = "";
 
 // read weight
 var dWeight = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bodyweight").value);
 
 // read gender & get weightclass
 var sGender = "";
  if (document.getElementById("male").checked == true ) {
   sGender = document.getElementById("male").value;
  }
  else {
   sGender = document.getElementById("female").value;
  }
 
 // read exercise values
 var irepsSquat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("reps_squat").value.replace(',','.'));
 var dweightSquat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight_squat").value.replace(',','.'));

 var irepsBench = parseFloat(document.getElementById("reps_bench").value.replace(',','.'));
 var dweightBench = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight_bench").value.replace(',','.'));

 var irepsDeadlift = parseFloat(document.getElementById("reps_deadlift").value.replace(',','.'));
 var dweightDeadlift = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight_deadlift").value.replace(',','.'));
 
 // check if reps & weight are valid -> calculate (Squat)
 if (check(irepsSquat) || check(dweightSquat)) {
  window.alert("Bitte Wiederholungen & Übungsgewicht eintragen");
  return;
 }
 else {
  var total_sq = calculate(irepsSquat, dweightSquat);
 }
 // check if reps & weight are valid -> calculate (Benchpress)
 if (check(irepsBench) || check(dweightBench)){
  window.alert("Bitte Wiederholungen & Übungsgewicht eintragen");
  return;
 }
 else {
  var total_bp = calculate(irepsBench, dweightBench);
 }
 // check if reps & weight are valid -> calculate (Deadlift)
 if (check(irepsBench) || check(dweightBench)){
  window.alert("Bitte Wiederholungen & Übungsgewicht eintragen");
  return;
 }
 else {
  var total_dl = calculate(irepsDeadlift, dweightDeadlift);
 }
 
 // calculate total & wilk points -> write it
 document.getElementById("total_squat").value = total_sq;
 document.getElementById("total_bench").value = total_bp;
 document.getElementById("total_deadlift").value = total_dl;
 
 var total_all = (parseFloat(total_sq) + parseFloat(total_bp) + parseFloat(total_dl)).toFixed(2);
 document.getElementById("total_all").value = total_all; 
             
 // Load the Visualization API
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
 
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadChartData(total_all));
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Checks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
function check(val) {
 if (isNaN(val)) {
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ calculate 1RM ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
function calculate(iReps, dWeightE) {
   return (dWeightE/(1.0278-(0.0278*iReps))).toFixed(2);
}
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

function loadChartData(total_all) {
 var dnorm1 = 300;
 var dnorm2 = 450;
 
 // Create the data table
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'label');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
 data.addRows([
   ['Own Total', parseFloat(total_all)],
   ['Kadernorm 1', parseFloat(dnorm1)], 
   ['Kadernorm 2', parseFloat(dnorm2)] 
 ]);
 drawChart(data);
}

function drawChart(data) {
 // Instantiate new chart
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
 
 // Set chart options
 var options = {'title':'Comparison of own Total vs. national team levels in kg',
       'width':700,
       'height':400,
       };

 // Draw chart, passing in some options
 chart.draw(data, options);

}
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setOnLoadCallback` takes a reference to a `function`
you're passing the result of a `function`, which doesn't `return` anything...

but don't really need `setOnLoadCallback`
include the `callback` in the `load` statement

but this will only be called when the page loads

to re-draw the chart afterwards, try something like this...

```
<script>
    var isInit = false;
    function initialize() {

      ...

      if (isInit) {
        loadChartData(total_all);
      } else {
        google.charts.load('current', {
          callback: function () {
            isInit = true;
            loadChartData(total_all);
          },
          packages:['corechart']
        });
      }
    }

    ...
```

Comment: hi WhiteHat, unfortunately this does not change how the code behaves. I replaced my code with yours, and it works one time. If I click the button a second time, the chart does not redraw itself... maybe the statement is only done once? is there a way to "destroy" the chart object? or can I refresh / redraw the chart with a different event?

Comment: kind of easy if you know how to do it :D thx man, it works now